# Elasticsearch - upgrade from version 5.0. to 5.2 - version downgrade caused by apt upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch on Ubuntu server.

I used `apt upgrade` command and elasticsearch got downgraded from version (I accepted all defaults in prompts) 5.2 to 5.0, at least Kibana says that:

> This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v5.2.0 on all nodes. I
>   found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v5.0.0

[image]

Is there any guide  on how to change version of elasticsearch?

Comment: How many nodes does your cluster have? It's saying one of the nodes(10.100.0.13) still has Elasticsearch 5.0. So [upgrade](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/rolling-upgrades.html) ES on that node it will fix the issue.

Comment: @avr Honestly I have no idea. I have never used elasticsearch, but I broke it with upgrade, how do I check list of nodes ?

Comment: You can run following command for one of running ES node: `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v"` . For more information check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/cat-health.html)

Comment: @avr I only have one node. `node.total = 1, node.data = 1`. Is there a curl request to change it's version to 5.2?

Comment: You can install ES 5.2 by following instructions provided in documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/deb.html). Stop the previous ES i.e ES 5.0 by running `sudo service elasticsearch stop` before install new one.

Comment: @avr Thanks that solved issue. However, kibana is empty, is it true that I destroyed all data?

Comment: If you had some data on old version of ES then pointing new ES to the same data directories can get you all the data into new one.

Comment: I found some data under `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/username/nodes/0/`, and college says that elastic data in thier interface is correct, also kibana started to display data too. Thank you very much, I will be able to handle it from here. Can you please post this as an asnwer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of following **comments** helped to resolve the issue(read comments under the question to get better idea):

How many nodes does your cluster have? It's saying one of the nodes(10.100.0.13) still has Elasticsearch 5.0. So upgrade ES on that node it will fix the issue.

You can run following command for one of running ES node:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v" .
```

You can install ES 5.2 by following instructions provided in documentation here. Stop the previous ES i.e ES 5.0 by running sudo service elasticsearch stop before install new one.

If you had some data on old version of ES then pointing new ES to the same data directories can get you all the data into new one.